# Plotting a step function with only horizontal lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use *ggplot2* to plot a step function using `geom_step()`.
What I need now is to get rid of the *vertical* lines.
This should be a quite common problem in math at least...

The [docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_step.html) do not mention such possibility .

Is there a hidden argument somewhere, or do I need to convert the data somehow so I can print individual lines for each datapoint?

#### TL;DR:

have `ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+geom_step()`

want `ggplot(data,aes(x,y))+geom_step(lines=horizontal)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read through this example.  You may want to remove the vline and play with the various parameters -- see http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=seq(0, 10), y=cumsum(rnorm(11)))
df$xend <- c(df$x[2:nrow(df)], NA)
df$yend <- df$y
p <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=x), linetype=2, color="grey") +
      geom_point() +  # Solid points to left
      geom_point(aes(x=xend, y=y), shape=1) +  # Open points to right
      geom_segment())  # Horizontal line segments
p
```

[image: output from ggsave]

Answer (score 2):

You can use geom_line with a group argument instead.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x,y,group=as.factor(x)))+geom_line()
```