# ggplot line graph shows overlap for discrete Y axis variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a time series plot using ggplot. I have a discrete variable that just describes if a vehicle engine was on or off through a given time.

Naturally, it should either be 0 or 1, there can't be an overlap. But as seen in the below plot, there's a considerable overlap.

I am pretty new to ggplot. Could someone please let me know what the issue is.

[image]

The code I am using is:

```
pd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = SampleTime, y = as.factor(Value))) + geom_line(color = 'black') + 
  labs(x = 'Time', y = 'Ignition Status', title = 'Ignition Status by Time') +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 hour', date_labels = '%H') +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18, face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black'))
```

structure of data:

```
str(pd)
'data.frame':   474 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ SampleTime: POSIXct, format: "2020-11-30 00:17:46" "2020-11-30 01:17:47" "2020-11-30 02:17:48" "2020-11-30 03:17:49" ...
 $ Value     : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
```

data used:

```
structure(list(SampleTime = structure(c(1606675666, 1606679267, 
1606682868, 1606686469, 1606690070, 1606693671, 1606697271, 1606700872, 
1606704473, 1606706974, 1606707066, 1606707129, 1606707192, 1606707255, 
1606707318, 1606707382, 1606707445, 1606707508, 1606707571, 1606707631, 
1606707694, 1606707754, 1606707817, 1606707880, 1606707943, 1606708006, 
1606708069, 1606708132, 1606708195, 1606708258, 1606708318, 1606708381, 
1606708441, 1606708504, 1606708567, 1606708630, 1606708691, 1606708751, 
1606708814, 1606708877, 1606708940, 1606709003, 1606709066, 1606709129, 
1606709192, 1606709255, 1606709318, 1606709381, 1606709444, 1606709507, 
1606709570, 1606709633, 1606709696, 1606709759, 1606709822, 1606709885, 
1606709948, 1606710011, 1606710074, 1606710137, 1606710200, 1606710263, 
1606710348, 1606710411, 1606710474, 1606710537, 1606710600, 1606710663, 
1606710726, 1606710789, 1606710852, 1606710915, 1606710978, 1606711041, 
1606711104, 1606711167, 1606711230, 1606711293, 1606711356, 1606711419, 
1606711482, 1606711545, 1606711608, 1606711671, 1606711734, 1606711797, 
1606711860, 1606711923, 1606711986, 1606712049, 1606712112, 1606712175, 
1606712238, 1606712301, 1606712365, 1606712428, 1606712491, 1606712553, 
1606712617, 1606712679, 1606712756, 1606712909, 1606712970, 1606713007, 
1606713034, 1606713094, 1606713157, 1606713220, 1606713283, 1606713346, 
1606713409, 1606713472, 1606713535, 1606713598, 1606713661, 1606713724, 
1606713787, 1606713850, 1606713913, 1606713976, 1606714039, 1606714102, 
1606714165, 1606714228, 1606714291, 1606714354, 1606714417, 1606714480, 
1606714543, 1606714606, 1606714669, 1606714732, 1606714795, 1606714858, 
1606714921, 1606714984, 1606715047, 1606715110, 1606715173, 1606715236, 
1606715299, 1606715362, 1606715425, 1606715488, 1606715551, 1606715614, 
1606715677, 1606715740, 1606715803, 1606715866, 1606715929, 1606715992, 
1606716055, 1606716118, 1606716181, 1606716244, 1606716307, 1606716370, 
1606716433, 1606716464, 1606716826, 1606716886, 1606716949, 1606717012, 
1606717075, 1606717138, 1606717201, 1606717264, 1606717327, 1606717390, 
1606717453, 1606717516, 1606717579, 1606717642, 1606717705, 1606717768, 
1606717831, 1606717894, 1606717957, 1606718021, 1606718084, 1606718147, 
1606718210, 1606718273, 1606718336, 1606718399, 1606718462, 1606718525, 
1606718588, 1606718651, 1606718714, 1606718777, 1606718839, 1606718903, 
1606718965, 1606719029, 1606719091, 1606719155, 1606719218, 1606719281, 
1606719344, 1606719407, 1606719470, 1606719533, 1606719596, 1606719659, 
1606719722, 1606719785, 1606719848, 1606719911, 1606719974, 1606720037, 
1606720100, 1606720163, 1606720226, 1606720289, 1606720352, 1606720415, 
1606720478, 1606720498, 1606721559, 1606721619, 1606721682, 1606721745, 
1606721808, 1606721871, 1606721934, 1606721997, 1606722060, 1606722123, 
1606722186, 1606722249, 1606722312, 1606722375, 1606722438, 1606722501, 
1606722564, 1606722627, 1606722690, 1606722753, 1606722816, 1606722858, 
1606722892, 1606722952, 1606723015, 1606723078, 1606723141, 1606723204, 
1606723267, 1606723330, 1606723393, 1606723456, 1606723519, 1606723582, 
1606723645, 1606723708, 1606723771, 1606723834, 1606723897, 1606723960, 
1606724023, 1606724086, 1606724149, 1606724212, 1606724275, 1606724338, 
1606724401, 1606724464, 1606724527, 1606724590, 1606724653, 1606724716, 
1606724779, 1606724842, 1606724905, 1606724968, 1606725031, 1606725094, 
1606725157, 1606725220, 1606725283, 1606725346, 1606725409, 1606725472, 
1606725535, 1606725598, 1606725661, 1606725721, 1606725784, 1606725840, 
1606729441, 1606730753, 1606730814, 1606730857, 1606731021, 1606731081, 
1606731144, 1606731207, 1606731270, 1606731333, 1606731396, 1606731459, 
1606731522, 1606731585, 1606731648, 1606731711, 1606731774, 1606731837, 
1606731900, 1606731963, 1606732026, 1606732089, 1606732138, 1606732956, 
1606733017, 1606733080, 1606733143, 1606733206, 1606733269, 1606733332, 
1606733395, 1606733458, 1606733521, 1606733584, 1606733647, 1606733710, 
1606733773, 1606733836, 1606733899, 1606733962, 1606734025, 1606734088, 
1606734151, 1606734203, 1606735128, 1606735189, 1606735252, 1606735315, 
1606735378, 1606735441, 1606735504, 1606735567, 1606735630, 1606735683, 
1606739285, 1606742885, 1606744969, 1606745030, 1606745093, 1606745156, 
1606745219, 1606745282, 1606745345, 1606745408, 1606745471, 1606745534, 
1606745597, 1606745660, 1606745723, 1606745786, 1606745849, 1606745912, 
1606745975, 1606746038, 1606746101, 1606746164, 1606746370, 1606746433, 
1606746496, 1606746559, 1606746702, 1606746736, 1606746765, 1606746828, 
1606746891, 1606746954, 1606747017, 1606747077, 1606747140, 1606747203, 
1606747266, 1606747329, 1606747392, 1606747455, 1606747518, 1606747581, 
1606747644, 1606747707, 1606747770, 1606747833, 1606747896, 1606747959, 
1606748022, 1606748085, 1606748145, 1606748206, 1606748269, 1606748332, 
1606748395, 1606748458, 1606748521, 1606748584, 1606748647, 1606748707, 
1606748770, 1606748833, 1606748896, 1606748959, 1606749022, 1606749085, 
1606749148, 1606749211, 1606749274, 1606749337, 1606749400, 1606749463, 
1606749526, 1606749589, 1606749652, 1606749715, 1606749778, 1606749841, 
1606749904, 1606749967, 1606750030, 1606750093, 1606750156, 1606750219, 
1606750282, 1606750345, 1606750408, 1606750471, 1606750534, 1606750597, 
1606750657, 1606750720, 1606750781, 1606750841, 1606750904, 1606750967, 
1606751030, 1606751084, 1606754686, 1606758287, 1606759153, 1606759213, 
1606759276, 1606759339, 1606759402, 1606759465, 1606759528, 1606759592, 
1606759654, 1606759718, 1606759780, 1606759843, 1606759906, 1606759969, 
1606760032, 1606760096, 1606760159, 1606760222, 1606760285, 1606760348, 
1606760411, 1606760474, 1606760537, 1606760600, 1606760663, 1606760726, 
1606760788, 1606760851, 1606760914, 1606760977), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -474L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You have second level data but you are plotting hourly data. In an hour engine can both be on and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ggplot` automatically connects the gaps between observations if you use `geom_line`. Try to use `geom_point` instead to see the gaps:

```r
pd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = SampleTime, y = as.factor(Value))) + 
  geom_point(color = 'black') + 
  labs(x = 'Time', y = 'Ignition Status', title = 'Ignition Status by Time') +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 hour', date_labels = '%H') +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18, face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black'))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `geom_line` but don't convert `Value` to a factor and use the numeric value instead. This way you can see the change from 0 to 1 more clearly:

```r
pd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = SampleTime, y = Value)) + 
  geom_line(color = 'black') + 
  labs(x = 'Time', y = 'Ignition Status', title = 'Ignition Status by Time') +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 hour', date_labels = '%H') +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18, face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black'))
```

[image]

Lastly, a slightly more appropriate option for categorical data might be to use `geom_step` instead, which at least connects the two categories with a vertical line:

```r
pd %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = SampleTime, y = Value)) + 
  geom_step(color = 'black') + 
  labs(x = 'Time', y = 'Ignition Status', title = 'Ignition Status by Time') +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '1 hour', date_labels = '%H') +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18, face = 'bold'),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black'))
```

[image]

If that doesn't suffice, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30733021/13534060) post on how to connect the lines between each consecutive dot per group via `geom_segment`.

Comment: "automatically connects the gaps" are you referring to the gaps in time or the x-axis? Yes I initially tried without changing to factor. But as you can see, there's a line that joins 0.00 and 1.00, which shouldn't really happen. A vehicle is either on or off.

Comment: I see your point regarding the lines, which are not really applicable to discrete variables. A slightly more appropriate option might be `geom_step`, which at least connects the dots via a vertical line. This [documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html) might also be helpful to learn how gaps are handled.