# Plot disconnected line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a chart with disconnected lines using ggplot

```
# Sample data
x <- seq(1:100)
y <- c(rnorm(25, mean = 1, sd = 1), rnorm(25, mean = 2, sd = 1), rnorm(25, mean = 3, sd = 1), rnorm(25, mean = 4, sd = 1))
z <- rep(1:4, each = 25)
tempdf <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

Using code

```
ggplot(data=tempdf, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = z), color = "red", size = 1)
```

I get this output

[image]

However I want to create something like (notice red lines are not connected at steps)

[image]

I tried using `geom_segment` but could not figure out the right way

```
ggplot(data=tempdf, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y), color = "blue") + 
    geom_segment(x = x, y = z, xend = x+25, yend = z)
```

gives this [image]

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729678/plotting-a-step-function-with-only-horizontal-lines) does not explain the issue clearly to me and answers are also very specific

Answer (score 2):

Use a `group` aesthetic to define which rows are connected:

```
ggplot(data=tempdf, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = y), color = "blue") + 
    geom_line(aes(y = z, group = z), color = "red", size = 1)
```

(This works in easily for your sample data with `group = z` because you want lines connected if they have the same `z` value AND the `z` values are unique. A more robust way would add a column for this purpose.)

[image]